# The deployment of the work items into the next stage failed

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error, devopscenter

I am using the salesforce DevOps center at the time of promotion from dev to UAT environment

**Admin of Type Profile failed to deploy due to Unknown user permission: CreateWorkBadgeDefinition**

[image]

Comment: Are you deploying admin profile?

Comment: Yes I am trying to deploy the admin profile using promotions pipelines dev to UAT

Answer (score 1):

There is a [know issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3pNAAS&title=error-profiles-admin-profile-admin-the-user-license-doesn-t-allow-the-permission-createworkbadgedefinition) for this. When trying to deploy system admin profiles users complained that they received this error. As per the workaround

set the permission to false as below.

```
  <userPermissions>
  <enabled>false</enabled>
  <name>CreateWorkBadgeDefinition</name>
  </userPermissions>
```

This work around might not work all the time if so   you need to deploy the changes in system admin manually.

Comment: I am using this setting under admin metadata XML file but still is true

Comment: You have to manually set it False

Comment: I did bro like this

  <userPermissions>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <name>CreateWorkBadgeDefinition</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>

but this profile did not deploy using the below command
sfdx force:source:push -f

Comment: Yeah got it. in the known issue link which I provided  it was mentioned that this may not work all the time

Comment: How to deploy this admin profile using sfdx?

I have changed the property to false but when I am trying to deploy this profile showing  No results found

Comment: @RohitKumar, Were you able to retrieve the profile ?